# New Apps Script IDE too helpful. Can you turn it off?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, monaco-editor

Any idea how to switch off the contextual help that covers your code above the line you are working on? It also covers the auto-complete which is super annoying.

[image]

Comment: ESC...........?

Comment: you could try clicking "use legacy editor" to go back to the old one

Comment: @Baby_Boy - feels like suggesting a guillotine as a remedy for headaches :) In all seriousness, though, the new editor is Monaco-based but is not as configurable as IDEs using the same engine (i.e. VS Code), which do have a setting for disabling autocompletion. michaeldon, if you want to, you can create a feature request on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: @OlegValter A guillotine a day...

Comment: @OlegValter I admit the new editor is great, but we put up with the old one for years and its not THAT bad (a little outdated)

Comment: @Baby_Boy - I somewhat agree - from the perspective of someone who moved to VS Code + CLASP a long time ago, the editor feels a bit painful. That said, the new deployment experience and the overall look is a blessing, so opting out feels like a downgrade. Wish the new one would contain more configuration options out of the box, but let's see how it matures - seems like it is no longer a low priority feature like the old IDE

Comment: I flip back and forth between new and legacy when I need different features and I always leave a comment explaining what I needed that was not available in the new editor. I hope someone is collecting the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no user preference setting to disable contextual help in the new Apps Script code editor.

Comment: However, you can use [tag:clasp] with your local ide.